# Showing the page after running the Server on a Grails Web Application

Tags: grails

Please , who can help me understanding this message showed on console after running the project on STS.

```
context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: taskmanagement1.Ressource.login() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: lock(), lock(), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: taskmanagement1.Ressource.login() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: lock(), lock(), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: taskmanagement1.Ressource.login() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: lock(), lock(), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: taskmanagement1.Ressource.login() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: lock(), lock(), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: taskmanagement1.Ressource.login() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: lock(), lock(), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: taskmanagement1.Ressource.login() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: lock(), lock(), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable), load(java.io.Serializable), lock(java.io.Serializable)
    at taskmanagement1.Ressource$__clinit__closure1.doCall(Ressource.groovy:19)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Can you add domain class `Ressource.groovy` as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a typo in the `constraints` block of the `Ressource` domain class. From the error it looks like you have something like

```
static constraints = {
   login blank: false
}
```

but there is no `login` property. If you had a `login` property and removed it, delete that constraint line, and if you renamed it make sure that all of the constrained property names are in sync with the domain class property names.